# Can someone help, what is the syntax errors?

Tags: linux

The following script is to accept one or more filenames as arguments and convert the filename to uppercase. But it has some syntax errors. Find the syntax errors and make the program work by testing convert arg1 arg2  ?

```
for file in $*
do
   ufile=`echo $file | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'`
   mv $file $ufile
done
```

Comment: you should seriously read some tutorial on shell scripting before starting scripting yourself.

Comment: I highly recommend [the Wooledge Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide).

Comment: Your script does not actually have any syntax errors. It has some bugs, though, like not handling file names with spaces. It has some limitations, like not uppercasing non-ASCII characters. What exactly are you asking us for help fixing?

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in $*
do
        ufile=$(echo $file | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]')
        mv $file $ufile
done
```

Comment: (1) ”Please do not feed the bears.” We try to discourage low-quality questions like this by not answering them. (2) The code in the question has two major errors (one of which appears multiple times), a couple of minor problems, and a cosmetic style issue. Guess what?  You fixed the ***least important*** one (the style issue), and left all the real problems.